# Is it possible to use (some) AOP concepts in existing C++ programs without complete refactoring?

Tags: c++, aop

I am reading on AOP now and would like to use (some) AOP ideas and approaches in my code. 
I don't have any third-party extensions, just MSVS 2005 environment. So, is it possible to benefit from AOP concepts in my day-to-day work without complete refactoring of the existing code (2-year old project x 5 programmers)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use AspectC++ compiler extension without changing much of you code. Just see AspectC++ and [tutorial](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=3&url=http%3A%2F%2Faosd.net%2F2004%2Ftutorials%2Faspectcpp.php&ei=IFa3SeawMJD67AOJi5WbCQ&usg=AFQjCNE9QZ9IUcheVdNbAN_AlXhJybTRPQ&sig2=xS1441_MXavFW8UWJv2dGg) for it.